# how can i change http respose code of the php page, on specific if condition depending upon response of ajax call in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

in my search page i call page using ajax which returns json data, now i want to set http response code of this page according result, if keyword found then remain default response code but if not found then change to  404. here is what i am trying.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php',
    data: u,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == null){
            <?php header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); ?>   //update header code to 404 
            $('#msh_warper').html(err_msg_m);
        } else if(data.msg == 'success'){
            $('#msh_warper').html(data.return_html);
            $('#total_rewr').html(data.total_re);
            $('#page_rec').html(data.page_rec);
        } else if(data.msg == 'error'){
            <?php header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); ?>   //update header code to 404 
            $('#msh_warper').html(data.return_html);
        } else {
            <?php header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); ?>   //update header code to 404 
            $('#msh_warper').html(err_msg_m);
        }
        $('.ml_warper').hide();
        $('#msh_warper').slideDown(1000);
        $('.page_overlay').hide();
    }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        <?php header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); ?>   //update header code to 404 
        $('#msh_warper').html(err_msg_m);

        $('.ml_warper').hide();
        $('#msh_warper').slideDown(1000);
        $('.page_overlay').hide();
    }
});
```

but in this case on every request it changes response code to 404, either it is success case or anyother.
can any body help me? can I change http response code on some specific if condition(fail case) which must not effect other (success case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix and match programming languages like that. Javascript is a client side language, and PHP is server side. Your PHP tags are going to be processed before the browser ever sees the javascript, so the first header tag you have is what's going to get served to the browser. Since the first PHP tag you have is sending a 404, that's why you always see that.

Aside from that, sending a 404 header when a search didn't return any results is really strange. 404 is for resource not found, not, "no results match your search". It would be much more standard to simply tell the user that there were no results found for their query.

Comment: it is SEO requirements. and not found message will also be displayed. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No. You can either send a 404 header, OR display and HTML message. If you're sending HTML to the client, then you've already sent a header, and can't send another one. In your case search.php would need to return a 404 header if results aren't found

Comment: in my case, as i have shown above, it return 404 header in any case, either found or not, that is the problem. i need to send this header in only case when keyword not found. is there any way to do this in javascript code, so that i can avoid php tags.